# Microsoft Guidelines for Collections: Confused about several parts

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, icollection

I'm looking at Microsoft's [Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I find a few parts hard to understand:

**X DO NOT use `ArrayList` or `List<T>` in public APIs**. Does this mean that I should avoid returning `List<T>` altogether, or that I could return it as an `IEnumerable`/`IList`, but not explicitly as `List<T>`?

**✓ DO use the least-specialized type possible as a parameter type. Most members taking collections as parameters use the `IEnumerable<T>` interface**. After seeing ReSharper complain about "possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable", I thought it was a better idea to take (and return) `ICollection<T>` when I was expecting a pre-computed, finite collection of objects (i.e. not a lazy stream). Isn't that the case?

**✓ DO use `Collection<T>` or a subclass of `Collection<T>` for properties or return values representing read/write collections**. Why not use `ICollection<T>`? I thought interfaces were preferable to concrete classes.

Comment: Do note that those guidelines where written in 2008 and have not been updated for versions newer than 3.5 of .NET and 3.0 of C#. Specifically the advice was written before the introduction of Covariance and Contravariance in 2010 with C# 4.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These guidleines exist to promote designing methods that are flexible in what they accept as parameters and in what they return as return types.

If you return a `List<T>` from a method, that method can never return anything that's *not* a `List<T>`. This may be fine in some scenarios but not so in others. For example, consider a method that returns a collection of users that logged in during a certain period. If this method returns just a `List<T>`, it has to acquire and return all users in a single pass because those are the semantics of `List`: you get all items with a total count as soon as the method returns. This may be a problem, if the number of users is several tens of thousands - it may take a long time to get all the records and they may take up a lot of memory.

If this method would return an `IEnumerable<T>`, there's no promise of a count or getting all items at once - the caller can iterate through the collection of items but not get all items in a single go. This allows the called method to return an object (implementing `IEnumerable<T>`) that collects the data in sevaral small batches and returns them one by one, as requested.

Also, many different collection types implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so another implementation of this method may actually decide to return a list instance, cast to `IEnumerable<T>`. The calling method won't know or care, since all it expects is an `IEnumerable<T>`. This is not the case with a hardcoded list type - it cannot be exchanged for anything else because it's already as concrete as possible.

In general, an generic collection interface will be the most flexible input parameter / return type for any method - an interface will allow you to implement it in a number of ways, mock it out, etc. so you have a lot of flexibility in controlling what gets passed or gets returned. An interface also doesn't (necessarily) have semantic limitations that may become inconvenient as a product evolves.

As for the first advice, `ArrayList` is an awful type that shouldn't ever be used after .NET 2.0, since the generic types are far better in every way possible.